# jQuery AutoComplete with remote data is getting the wrong url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to get jQuery-autocomplete working with a remote data source in a Ruby on Rails project. The input is on `http://localhost:3000/file_analysis/new`, when I type some terms in the input it requests `http://localhost:3000/file_analysis/new?query=some_terms` while it should request `http://localhost:3000/diagnoses/types?term=some_terms`. Does anyone know why this happens?

My javascript code:

```
$('#element_id').autocomplete({
    source : "/diagnoses/types"
});
```

I have read a lot of questions about this, but most of them are outdated (2009-2011) and also provide different answers that do not work for me. Also the demos from the official site are not really clear to me.

Comment: Have you checked you're using the latest jQuery UI version?

Comment: Hmm, although I had the newest version installed, I have downloaded it again. This solved the problem. The old file must have gotten corrupted i guess. Thanks for the help!

Comment: which auto complete jquery plugin u are using in ur application ? please share the link.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CornéM suggests, this problem can occur when you have an older version of jQuery UI. The answer is a simple update :-)